# React/Redux component not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I am new to using Redux and cannot figure out why my Sidebar component is not being updated to open the drawer. I can see that my action is getting called but it doesn't seem to trigger any update in my component. I have tried to follow the Redux documentation and I can't see what I am missing as I have set my code up the same way.

I didn't want to fill the post up with code but let me know if you need any more information to help solve this. I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

**Solution:** I was using the wrong property on the state object so my component wasn't being updated. It should have been state.Sidebar.open not state.open.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state:any) => ({  
    open: state.Sidebar.open
});
```

Menu container:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { toggleSidebar } from '../actions';
import Menu from '../components/Menu/Menu';

const mapStateToProps = (state:any) => ({  
    open: state.open ? state.open : false
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch:any) => ({
  toggleSidebar: (open:boolean) => dispatch(toggleSidebar(open))
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Menu);
```

Menu component:

```
class Menu extends React.Component<IMenuProps> { 
    private handleDrawerOpen = () => {        
        this.props.toggleSidebar(true);
    }

    private handleDrawerClose = () => {
        this.props.toggleSidebar(false);
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MenuBar 
                    handleDrawerOpen={this.handleDrawerOpen}
                />
                <SideBar
                    open={this.props.open} 
                    handleDrawerClose={this.handleDrawerClose}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Sidebar:

```
class Sidebar extends React.Component<ISideBarProps> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Drawer 
          open={this.props.open} 
          onClose={this.props.handleDrawerClose}>

          <div
            tabIndex={0}
            role="button"
          >
            <AdministrationItems />
          </div>
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

*Edit
Reducer:

```
const sidebar = (state = { open: false }, action:any) => {  
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_SIDEBAR: {       
      return {
        open: action.open
      };
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

Action:

```
export const toggleSidebar = (open:boolean) => ({
    open,
    type: TOGGLE_SIDEBAR,    
});
```

Comment: Do you have the proper reducers set up to assign `open` to the state?

Comment: I believe so, I have edited the question to include the action and reducer

Comment: I don't know much about Redux, but I'll fiddle with this if you publish a complete code example either as a git repository or on a service like CodeSandbox or Stackblitz.

Comment: Okay thank you, I'll work on adding it now

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is in the reducer. Try replacing the reducer with:

```js
const sidebar = (state = { open: false }, action:any) => {  
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_SIDEBAR: {       
      return {
        ...state,
        open: action.open
      };
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

You should always spread the state for every case. Let me know if it worked

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't fixed it the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: I was using the wrong property on the state object so my component wasn't being updated. It should have been state.Sidebar.open not state.open.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state:any) => ({  
    open: state.Sidebar.open
});
```